# Change the selected TabBar index on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

In my app I have 4 tabs, on the first Tab : I have 4 views. on second view,there is one button which will open the third tab view. But my selected tab Index is One. How can I chage it to Third.

My code for tab bar is in APPDelegate as follow:

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
     UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
         UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[CarAccidentAppViewController alloc]
     initWithNibName:@"CarAccidentAppViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil]
     autorelease];
        nav1.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, nil];

         //for steps tab...

         UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
         UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[FirstSteps alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstSteps" bundle:nil] autorelease];
         nav2.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController2, nil];

         //for profiles tab...

        UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
         UIViewController *viewController3 = [[[Profiles alloc] initWithNibName:@"Profiles" bundle:nil] autorelease];
         nav3.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController3, nil];

         //for contact us tab...

        UINavigationController *nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
        UIViewController *viewController4 = [[[ContactUs alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactUs" bundle:nil] autorelease];
         nav4.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController4, nil]; self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init]
     autorelease];
         self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4 ,nil];

         self.window.rootViewController=self.tabBarController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
         return YES; 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In **Swift** 2, you can just call:

```
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to programatically switch tabs within the app is by doing this ..

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
```

I use this in one of my apps and it works extremely well.

Plasma

Comment: but i want to go second view of third tab

Comment: There may be other ways of doing it but I'd set a variable somewhere, which I would read on the viewDidLoad of the tab. So you set myVC = 2 then switch to Tab 3 and as it loads it would check myVc which you previously set to 2 and load up the 2nd view controller.

Answer (score 1):

On Button Click

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:YourView animated:YES];
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:index];
```

Comment: This works fine in my app, I replied to the question before I realised Rajneesh071 had posted the same code snippet.

Comment: but i want to go second view of third tab

Comment: just navigate to your second view on button click....and set tabBarIndex = 3..chk my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

```
 self.tabBarController.selectedViewController=[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];
```

Try this. This will helpful for you.

Comment: it is work but i goes to third tab's first view. I want to go third tab's second view controller.