# change the view on button clicked in tabbar app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

In my tab based app, I programetically created the tabbar app with 4 tabs. In my first tab there is 5 scrren & in 3rd tab there is 3 screens.

On my first tab's 2nd screen when i click one button i want it should go to 2nd screen in 3rd tab. But now it go to the screen which is last open on 3rd tab.

e.g. tabControllers: a,b,c,d

```
a tab: 1->2>3>4>5

C  tab:  1>2>3
```

I want selected tab is a: & screen is: 3 &

click button on that screen go to

selected tab is C & screen is 2nd

reference link is:
[Change the selected TabBar index on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313820/change-the-selected-tabbar-index-on-button-click)

My code is as follow:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 //for home tab..
    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[CarAccidentAppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CarAccidentAppViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    nav1.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, nil];

    //for steps tab...
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[FirstSteps alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstSteps" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    nav2.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController2, nil];

    //for profiles tab...
    UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[[Profiles alloc] initWithNibName:@"Profiles" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    nav3.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController3, nil];

    //for contact us tab...
    UINavigationController *nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[[ContactUs alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactUs" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    nav4.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController4, nil];


    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4 ,nil];

    self.window.rootViewController=self.tabBarController;
      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}

//Button click event 
-(IBAction)btnNewDriverPressed:(id)sender
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:0 forKey:@"showselectedIndex"];
    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController=[self.tabBarController.viewControllers 
objectAtIndex:2];
}
```

Comment: [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController=[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];

Comment: not working remain my problem same

Answer (score 0):

Please upload your flow with images that explains what you actually want to achieve.

navigate through your desire `viewcontroller`/`screen` using `initwithnibname` method.

Follow :

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: i can't upload images due to less points. you can read comment by @piyush on reference link

Comment: edit your answer not adding new answer in case u have alternative

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you cannot make it work.. if you are in "C" tab with first screen,you will goto second screen by clicking any button only. By pressing c tab,its not gonna load second view controller to your navigation controller without pressing any button. so you need to push to second screen yourself and select the c tab too.. But from my opinion your app design is not good if you do like that. Its not gonna give best user experience.

Comment: i think you misunderstood. like i am in "A" tab with 2nd screen & on that button click i want to go second screen of "C" tab

Comment: thats what i m saying.. you have to push to that view controller in that view currently you are.. you cannot use tabbar controller to direct to the second screen without load that view controller in your tabbar controller.

Comment: ok can you help me with only that when i clicked on button it always open the rootview controller of 3rd tab. is it possible??